# Using a factory to generate Model with ManyToMany via a through class for testing

Tags: python, django

I have the following model which I would like to generate using Factory-boy (or something similar) in my tests:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    questiongroup=models.ManyToManyField(QuestionGroup, through='QuestionGroup_order')
```

Where QuestionGroup_order is:

```
class QuestionGroup_order(models.Model):
    questiongroup=models.ForeignKey(QuestionGroup)
    questionnaire=models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    order_info=models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
```

Does anyone know how to do this using something like Factory-Boy or can you suggest an alternative approach (apart from using fixtures which is what I am currently doing)?